# iterating a jquery function over multiple classes

Tags: jquery

I am trying to finish this jquery function.  The goal is to input a single value and return the correct percentage in each table cell.  I have it working so that it fills in the first cell, but I want the classes to be all the same and have a single input populate each cell with the percentage of that input.

```
<input class="max1" />
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5">Deadlift</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <span  class="perc1">75</span>% x 3</td>
        <td align="center">
            <span class="perc">78</span>% x 2</td>
        <td align="center">
            <span class="perc">83</span>% x 1</td>
        <td align="center">
            <span class="perc">85</span>% x 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="weight1"></td>
        <td class="weight"></td>
        <td class="weight"></td>
        <td class="weight"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input').keyup(function () {
        cal(this);
    });
});

function cal(obj) {
    var cal1, perc1, result;
    cal1 = parseFloat(obj.value);
    perc1 = parseFloat($('.perc1').text());


    result = (cal1*perc1)/100;
    $('.weight1').html(result);
}
</script>
```

Comment: can you clarify a little bit exactly?then we can help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input').keyup(function () {
        cal(this);
    });
});

function cal(obj) {
    var cal1, perc1, result;
    cal1 = parseFloat(obj.value);
 $.each($(".perc"),function(key,val){
  var perc1, result;
  perc1 = parseFloat($(val).text());
  result = (cal1*perc1)/100;
  $($('.weight')[key]).html(result);
 });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="max1" />
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5">Deadlift</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <span  class="perc">75</span>% x 3</td>
        <td align="center">
            <span class="perc">78</span>% x 2</td>
        <td align="center">
            <span class="perc">83</span>% x 1</td>
        <td align="center">
            <span class="perc">85</span>% x 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="weight"></td>
        <td class="weight"></td>
        <td class="weight"></td>
        <td class="weight"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This can be extended for multiple tables as well(According to your request). There are number of ways to do this. I don't know your requirement and DOM structure exactly. But if each table just after the input element then you can use following solution. If not you have to assign specific class for the input and related table.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input').keyup(function () {  
        cal(this,$(this).next());
    });
});

function cal(obj,tableObj) {
    var cal1, perc1, result;
    cal1 = parseFloat(obj.value);
 $.each($(tableObj).find(".perc"),function(key,val){
  var perc1, result;
  perc1 = parseFloat($(val).text());
  result = (cal1*perc1)/100;
  $($(tableObj).find('.weight')[key]).html(result);
 });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="max1" />
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5">Deadlift</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <span  class="perc">75</span>% x 3</td>
        <td align="center">
            <span class="perc">78</span>% x 2</td>
        <td align="center">
            <span class="perc">83</span>% x 1</td>
        <td align="center">
            <span class="perc">85</span>% x 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="weight"></td>
        <td class="weight"></td>
        <td class="weight"></td>
        <td class="weight"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
.......................................................................<br/>
<input class="max1" />
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5">Deadlift</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <span  class="perc">75</span>% x 3</td>
        <td align="center">
            <span class="perc">78</span>% x 2</td>
        <td align="center">
            <span class="perc">83</span>% x 1</td>
        <td align="center">
            <span class="perc">85</span>% x 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="weight"></td>
        <td class="weight"></td>
        <td class="weight"></td>
        <td class="weight"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
.......................................................................<br/>
<input class="max1" />
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5">Deadlift</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <span  class="perc">75</span>% x 3</td>
        <td align="center">
            <span class="perc">78</span>% x 2</td>
        <td align="center">
            <span class="perc">83</span>% x 1</td>
        <td align="center">
            <span class="perc">85</span>% x 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="weight"></td>
        <td class="weight"></td>
        <td class="weight"></td>
        <td class="weight"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This works great! Thank you so much for the help.  I couldn't quite figure out how to implement the .each() function to iterate properly.

Comment: @tcreamer You should accept this answer if it solved your issue. By clicking on right symbol.

Comment: @nishan, If you don't mind, would you be able to help show me how I would implement this for multiple tables on the same page?  For example, 3 inputs and 3 tables, and  each input only corresponding to the table below it.  I would greatly appreciate it, if it is not too much to ask

Answer (score 0):

Ok based on your description I think you need a simple `$.each` to iterate over all td span and set your input percentage like this.

```
$('table').find('tr:not(:first)').find('td').each(function() {
   $this = $(this);
   $this.find("span.perc").html('your value');
});
```